# How to solve the method missing error in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a model Dish and PriceDeal as follows

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :price_deal
end

class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dish
end
```

In rails console, I want to retrive the discountPercent value like this.

```
1.9.2p290 :130 > pd=PriceDeal.find(17)
 => #<PriceDeal id: 17, name: "deal1", description: "my deal1", discountPercent: 20.0, discountCash: nil, dish_id: 2, created_at: "2012-03-22 07:42:08", updated_at: "2012-04-16 11:16:49"> 

1.9.2p290 :131 > pd.discountPercent
 => 20.0
```

I got the expected result.

But when I try to get the value like this,

```
1.9.2p290 :132 > pd1 = PriceDeal.where(:dish_id => 2)
 => [#<PriceDeal id: 17, name: "deal1", description: "my deal1", discountPercent: 20.0, discountCash: nil, dish_id: 2, created_at: "2012-03-22 07:42:08", updated_at: "2012-04-16 11:16:49">] 

1.9.2p290 :133 > pd1.discountPercent

NoMethodError: undefined method `discountPercent' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xa134958>
    from /home/ragunathjawahar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/activerecord-3.0.11/lib/active_record/relation.rb:374:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):133
    from /home/ragunathjawahar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /home/ragunathjawahar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/ragunathjawahar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I got error,

How to get the value of discountPercent from pd1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because when you use `where`, you get back not a single object of type `PriceDeal`, but you get an object of type `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which for all intents and purposes is an array.

Notice how you got:

```
[#<PriceDeal id: 17, name: "deal1", ... >]
```

Instead of just:

```
#<PriceDeal id: 17, name: "deal1", ... >
```

The braces (`[]`) mean that it's an array. So you'll have to do this:

```
pd1.first.discountPercent
```

The reason why the `where` method returns an array is because you can have multiple items returned. Imagine doing:

```
PriceDeal.where("discountPercent >= 0")
```

You'd probably get a lot of records from that.

Comment: Yeah that's probably a better way of putting, since relations looks for array methods first, then class methods.

Answer (score 0):

pd=PriceDeal.find(17)

It will return only one particular column.so you will not get no method error.

when you are using Modelname.where("conditions").The results will be array.so you will get no method error.Because your method is not present to array.